# lxml - saving as html file

Tags: python, python-2.7, lxml

In this code,

```
import lxml.html as ht
page=ht.parse("http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/_static/selectors-sample1.html")
```

I want to save the html page as an html file at a specific path/folder. How do I do it?

Comment: Why do you need to parse it with `lxml` if you only want to download and save it?..

Comment: maybe I want to process it a bit before saving :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use:

```
page.write('test.html')
```

This will output the file to your working directory. You can output the file to another directory if you specify an appropriate path.

Comment: Specifiy the method for a real html file. Otherwise it will write a xml-file: `page.write('test.html, method='html')`. https://lxml.de/api/lxml.etree._ElementTree-class.html#write